# "Meteor way" for writing jQuery blur/focus

Tags: jquery, meteor

I currently have a jQuery function that I use to track whether or not the current page is focused or not like so..

```
$(window).on("blur focus", (e) ->
    prevType = $(this).data("prevType")
    if prevType != e.type
        if e.type == "blur"
            ...
        else if e.type == "focus"
            ...
    $(this).data("prevType", e.type)
)
```

I want to move this code away from raw jQuery into a `Template.template.events` hash, but am unsure how to do so, or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding an event to the `window`, not an html element inside a template, therefore there is no need to use `Template.events`.

You can move this code anywhere, but some type of startup script or global events would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't bind events directly to the window using an event hash, you can bind body-level events using `UI.body.events(hash)`.

For an example of how I've set up window-level blur/focus events in a Meteor package, see https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status/blob/master/monitor.coffee#L151.